# Sending POST request to a google cloud signed url return 403 forbidden

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I created a signed URL with the Google Cloud Storage API with the following code:

```
url, err := s.client.Bucket(s.bucketName).SignedURL(filename, &storage.SignedURLOptions{
        GoogleAccessID: jwtConf.Email,
        PrivateKey:     jwtConf.PrivateKey,
        Expires:        s.ExpirationTime,
        ContentType:    s.ContentType,
        Scheme:         storage.SigningSchemeV4,
        Method:         "POST",
        Headers:        []string{"x-goog-custom-time:2022-12-12T23:20:50Z", "x-goog-resumable:start",
    })
```

I got the following signed url:

> https://storage.googleapis.com/####/test_file?X-Goog-Algorithm=GOOG4-RSA-SHA256&X-Goog-Credential=####%40####%2F20221030%2Fauto%2Fstorage%2Fgoog4_request&X-Goog-Date=20221030T122044Z&X-Goog-Expires=3578&X-Goog-Signature=####&**X-Goog-SignedHeaders=host%3Bx-goog-custom-time%3Bx-goog-resumable**

**The url contains the signed headers as I expected.**
When I send a request to start a resumable upload of the file, I get 403 forbidden error.
This is my request:

```
curl --location --request POST '<my_signed_url>' \
--header 'content-length: 0' \
--header 'content-type: application/json' \
--header 'x-goog-custom-time: 2022-12-12T23:20:50Z' \
--header 'x-goog-resumable: start'
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<Error><Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
<Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your Google secret key and signing method.</Message>
<StringToSign>GOOG4-RSA-SHA256
20221030T122044Z
20221030/auto/storage/goog4_request
ea35f34d2dc65e9345e5a40a4f76ecddbd306cc25a9e19fa97e056cdd2f0363a</StringToSign><CanonicalRequest>POST
/####/test_file
X-Goog-Algorithm=GOOG4-RSA-SHA256&amp;X-Goog-Credential=####;X-Goog-Date=20221030T122044Z&amp;X-Goog-Expires=3578&amp;X-Goog-SignedHeaders=host%3Bx-goog-custom-time%3Bx-goog-resumable
host:storage.googleapis.com
x-goog-custom-time:2022-12-12T23:20:50Z
x-goog-resumable:start

host;x-goog-custom-time;x-goog-resumable
UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD</CanonicalRequest></Error>
```

**When removing the `x-goog-custom-time` header from both requests, the POST request succeeds.**
Thanks for getting this far:)
Any ideas on why would this fail would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Can you share the code that you are using to create the signed URL? By chance are you trying to use a [PUT signed URL](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/samples/storage-generate-upload-signed-url-v4) to upload files?

Comment: Hey @Dharmaraj, added the call to SignedURL() to my question. I'm creating a signed url for a POST request because it's a resumable upload request.

Comment: Adding `Host: storage.googleapis.com` header in the upload initiate request seems to be working. Can you please check this on your end? [`Host`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/post-object-resumable) is required header.

Comment: @Dharmaraj the ```host``` header is added by default, but I think the problem is that in the source code of the ```SignURL()``` function, when they're parsing the headers they're splitting each header by ```":"``` which causes them to lose a part of the date..

Comment: I was referring to the cURL request. What is the host header value in that? `--header 'host: storage.googleapis.com'`

Comment: @Dharmaraj I tried, unfortunately that doesn't help (I still get the same error)

Comment: It's working for me with the `Host` error and I can reproduce the error only when I remove it. I did notice your error does not include `Content-Type` listed in `x-goog-SignedHeaders`. Maybe try adding Host and removing the ContentType from your cURL request. Or before that try passing `Content-Type` in `Headers` along with others while generating the URL and then check once

Comment: @Dharmaraj actually my request does include host, you can see in the error in the question. I cannot pass ```Content-Type``` as one service will generate the URL (and is unaware of the data type) and another one will upload the data.